# Is there a way to Iterate over elements in recycler view

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project and I have to implement an option that will call an API but for that I need a name that is stored in a recyclerview.And perhaps I have 10 cardview elements so I want the names of that 10 elements.

Comment: Just iterate over your data set. RecyclerView (and its items) exist purely in view layer as means to represent it - "offscreen" items will not even have viewholders bound to them. Any changes made (to edit texts I assume?) in those viewholders should immediately be reflected in your data set in order to persist them.

Comment: Yes i have a list that has all the objects, but when i try to return getItemCount it returns 0